# How to show convergence in a $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I've come across a chapter in my book which has me stumped and nowhere can I find so that I can move on. The question is "Using the definition 9.1i, prove that the following limits exist:
a) $$x_k = \left(\frac 1k, 1 - \frac {1}{k²}\right)$$
Def 9.1i being: "Let ${x_k}$ be a sequence of points in $R^n$ then ${x_k}$ is said to converge to some point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (called the limit of ${x_k}$) if and only if for every $\epsilon$>0 there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$k\ge N $$ implies $$||x_k - a|| < \epsilon."$$

I cannot use the definition to get the answer. My work is just to find the limit of $\frac1k$ which is easy stuff and get $x_k\rightarrow$ 0 as $k\rightarrow \infty$ and the same process for $1 - \frac {1}{k²}$ to get 1 and so $x_k \rightarrow (0,1)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.
Reading on the matter has lead me to believe I should be doing this far better but I really haven't got any clue how to use the definition. Please help.

Comment: In my own practice, I would use the fact that norms on finite dimensional spaces are all equivalent to just pick a convenient norm for the problem and prove it that way. But that result is significantly harder to prove than your result. Consequently we really need to know what norm you are using in order to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found your guess of what the limit should be, $(0,1)$, so to use the definition of convergence of a sequence, for every $\epsilon>0$, you just need to find a positive integer $N$ such that $k\geq N$ implies $|x_{k}-(0,1)| = |(\frac{1}{k} - 0, 1 - \frac{1}{k^2} - 1)| = |(\frac{1}{k},-\frac{1}{k^2})| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{k^4}} < \epsilon$ assuming you are using the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Here, since $k>0$, and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0},$ $\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{k^4}} = \sqrt{\frac{k^2 + 1}{k^4}} = \frac{\sqrt{k^2+1}}{k^2}\leq \frac{\sqrt{k^2+3k^2}}{k^2} = \frac{\sqrt{4k^2}}{k^2} = \frac{2}{k}$.

So let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then by the archimediean property of $\mathbb{R}$, you can find a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So then, taking $k\geq N$ implies $|x_{k}-(0,1)| \leq \frac{2}{k} \leq \frac{2}{N} < \epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

As said in Ian's comment, we can choose our norm ; let $\|.\|$ be the euclidian norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is
$$\|\left(z_1,z_2\right)\|=\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\quad\quad\quad z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Now, let
$$x_k=\left(\frac{1}{k},1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\quad\quad\quad k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$$
and
$$a=\left(0,1\right).$$
Then one has
$$\|x_k-a\|^2=\left(\frac{1}{k}-0\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}-1\right)^2=\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^4}<\frac{2}{k^2}\quad\quad\quad k>1.$$
Now let $\varepsilon>0$ ; for all $k\geq K$ with
$$K=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\varepsilon},$$
one has
$$\|x_k-a\|<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{k}\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{K}=\varepsilon.$$
Hence, $x_k\to a$ when $k\to+\infty$.

**EDIT :**

In the definition of the question, $K$ must be integer, so the precedent proof must be adapted to it. As mentioned by catfish, we can use the archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ to find $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\varepsilon}$ (for example, we can choose $K=\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\varepsilon}\rfloor+1$).

Comment: $K$ need not be an integer here right? I think we need to use the archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ here to get an integer $N$ with $N\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @catfish It can be real valued. Actually, what it matters is that the index $k$ is integer. Now, the definition in the original post uses integers, so we must use the archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, you're right. I will edit my post to emphasize this point. Thank you!